# How to align this structure in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm developing a page's div part as like in below image.
[image]

I heard about offset but I didn't use the offset. I've tried with some code given below.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="text-center service-text">
               <h1>our best services</h1>
               <h2>business valuation</h2>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce cursus leo orci.</p>
                <img src="images/ser_icon_1.png">
             </div> 
        </div>
  <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4"></div>
 </div>
```

But it results the div was aligned to the left.[image]

How can I make empty space between the left and right side?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: h1,h2,p are block level elements so it will occupy full width, try giving them in span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="text-center service-text">
               <h1>our best services</h1>
               <h2>business valuation</h2>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce cursus leo orci.</p>
                <img src="images/ser_icon_1.png">
             </div> 
        </div>
 </div>
```

This should do it, [Here](https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/9Xbrj)'s a snippet with this code working with bootstrap.
Your two divs around the main one are useless, if you want to give a div an offset, give it both the `col-md-offset-x` and `col-md-x` classes.

Comment: Thanks @Antione  Thiry